# Retrieve row and column titles based on cell value in a large array

Tags: excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExRKK.png)

I have a 6 by 6 table. I have pulled the top 10 values out of this table using the large function.

I need the table headers, both row and column for the large values I pulled. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive all values are unique you could use SUMPRODUCT combined with INDEX:
`=INDEX($4:$4,, SUMPRODUCT(($C$5:$H$10=C13)*COLUMN($C$5:$H$10)))`

Index the header row and SUMPRODUCT returns TRUE or FALSE (1 or 2) for your range to equal the value and multiplies that by the column number. So all cells in the range with false match return `0*column #` and for the true match it returns `1*column #`

[image]

Retrieving the row number works in the same logic:
`=INDEX($4:$4, SUMPRODUCT(($C$5:$H$10=C13)*ROW($C$5:$H$10)))`

Comment: Thank you that worked. i really appreciate it

Comment: @dhruv If this solved your query, please mark the answer as accepted